# Changing the locale of date picker filter mui data grid

Tags: material-ui

I'm trying to change the date format to US (mm/dd/yyyy) for the data grid filter menu.

I have added `localeText={enUS.components.MuiDataGrid.defaultProps.localeText}` to  but this does not change the datepicker in the filter menu.

Noteable: the dates in the data grid are in the US format

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the DatePicker component

`inputFormat="MM/DD/YYYY"`

also you can set mask.

`mask="__/__/____"'`

Comment: I'm not using the datepicker component implicitly, all filter options are created automatically when using DataGrid.  
In columns I have set the valuegetter and valueformatter but it is not changing the format.